# Программа не даёт возможности считать пользовательский ввод

Tags: java

```
package out.production.javaworks;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {

String name;
int age;
String gender;

public void printText(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
public Person() {
}

public Person(String name, int age, String gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender  = gender;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Person project = new Person();
    Person people1 = new Person("", 0, "");

    System.out.println("Введите Ваше имя:");
    people1.name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введите Ваш возраст:");
    people1.age = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите Ваш пол (гендер):");
    people1.gender = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Привет, " + people1.name + "!");
 }
}
```

---

После строки "Введите Ваш пол (гендер):" не успеваю ввести данные и выполняются следующие инструкции (вывод текста)
С чем это связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что `nextInt` не считывает конец строки.

```
...
System.out.println("Введите Ваш возраст:");
people1.age = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Введите Ваш пол (гендер):");
people1.gender = scanner.nextLine();
...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, сработало))
Не могли бы поделиться, почему это сработало

Comment: @НикитаПопов `nextInt` не считывает конец строки.